# Android Task Killers

Tags: android, save, state, task

Users of my app are complaining that it is not saving state. I found out they are using task killers after finishing from the app. I know since Android 2.2 its ok. What can I implement to still save state in this scenario? Or are the task killers too brutally and we are unable to implement anything to mitigate this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) docs:

> `onPause()` is where you deal with the
>   user leaving your activity. Most
>   importantly, any changes made by the
>   user should at this point be committed
>   (usually to the `ContentProvider`
>   holding the data).

Comment: Yes that is where my data is saving but when task killers are used that does not work.

Comment: If the users are using task killers to kill active tasks before they had a chance to react to onPause, there's nothing the app can do, aside from saving its state every 100ms or so - but then the cure is worse than the illness...

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to make a menu exit button and call finish(); which gracefully shutsdown the app by calling pause, stop and then destroy. Then in the users mind it is no longer using space and the game is saved.